# SQL Server avoid precision lost

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I'm trying to load some data from CSV files that have numbers with very high precision, in SQL Server 2014 what data types should I use in order to avoid precision lost?

Some sample of data:

```
-0.00740740740740741
-0.351706036745407
0.029673590504451
-67.68
```

Comment: A double wouldn't be big enough for that first one. It'll have to be a wide decimal type.

Answer (score 2):

Use **[`DECIMAL(38,18)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx)**:

```
CREATE TABLE #tbl(col DECIMAL(38,18));

INSERT INTO #tbl(col)
VALUES(-0.00740740740740741),(-0.351706036745407),(0.029673590504451),(-67.68);

SELECT *
FROM #tbl;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/376985)**</kbd>

If needed you can change scale from 18 up to 38.